# How do I rebase a git superproject changing the hashes of the submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, rebase

#### Background

Assume we have two git repos, one a submodule of the other (`A` will be the superproject, `B` will be the submodule). Project `A` is not source code per-se, rather a project that gathers and tracks information about its submodule(s). The `A` repo rarely, if ever, exists on local machines, rather a bunch of scripts keep it updated.

One day, someone realized that repo `B` should have been using LFS better and cleaned up the repo using `git lfs migrate import`. I have a list of `B`'s old hashes and new hashes.

#### What I did

As repo `A` happens to linear (no branching), I was able to do a `git rebase --root -i`, change all the commits to `edit`, and run a simple bash script that reset the submodule to the new hashes. Here's an example of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#set the submodule path and input files
submodulePath=foo
newHashesFile=NewHashes.txt
originalHashesFile=OriginalHashes.txt

while [ (test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)" ) ]; do
    numLines=`git ls-files --stage | grep $submodulePath | wc -l`
    if [ $numLines = 1 ];
    then
        oldHash=`git ls-files --stage | grep $submodulePath | sed -e 's/^160000 \([^ ]*\) 0.*$/\1/g'`
        echo oldHash: $oldHash
    else
        echo merge conflict
        oldHash=`git ls-files --stage | grep $submodulePath | grep '^160000 \([^ ]*\) 3.*' | sed -e 's/^160000 \([^ ]*\) 3.*$/\1/g'`
        echo oldHash: $oldHash    
    fi

    lineNumber=`grep -n $oldHash $originalHashesFile | sed -e 's/^\([^:]*\):.*/\1/g'`
    newHash=`head -n $lineNumber $newHashesFile | tail -n 1`

    if [ ! $lineNumber ];
    then
        echo Hash not changed
    else
        cd $submodulePath
        git reset --hard $newHash
        cd ../
    fi

    git add $submodulePath/
    git commit --amend
    git rebase --continue
done
```

#### Question

All this worked, but I was wondering if there is an easier simpler way to do so, as I assume I'll be called on to do this again. There are two parts to that question.

1. Is there a simple way to tell git that you want the default to be `edit` instead of `pick`, not dependent on the editor?
2. Is there a simpler way of telling git to do what the script does? Would it help if I did the `git lfs migrate import` from within the superproject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to tell git that you want the default to be edit instead of pick, not dependent on the editor?

No.  There is, however, a way to set the sequence-of-commands editor to a separate editor from other editors: set the environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`.  So, for instance, you can do:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '' s/^pick/edit/" git rebase -i ...
```

(assuming your `sed` has a `-i` that works this way, etc).

> Is there a simpler way of telling git to do what the script does?

Given that you want to update each gitlink hash, I'd use `git filter-branch` (rather than `git rebase`) to do it, with an `--index-filter` that does the gitlink hash updates.  I'm not sure this is any *simpler* but it's more direct.  The index filter itself would consist of using `git ls-files --stage` similar to the way you do it, but probably itself use a generated `sed` script, or an `awk` script.  Generated-sed would probably be faster, while awk would be simpler, especially if you have a modern awk where you can just read in the hash mapping.

Comment: I only have time to check the first half and it works for me with `"sed -i s/^pick/edit/"`. I am running this on a Windows machine, and mingw does all sorts of (not quite what I'd expect) stuff. +1. I'll check the `filter-branch` next week.

Comment: Got it, I think. Basically, I'd place roughly the entire script (or call it) from the `--index-filter` argument. This would really only save time, as the working copy won't be updated, correct? Also, if I had a branched repo, then I could treat all the branches at once.

Comment: Right on both: the filter-branch index-filter just treats the commits themselves, saving a bit of time (probably not very much in this case), and more importantly, you can cover arbitrary branch graphs.

Comment: I finally took your advice and rewrote the bash script as a `filter-branch` with `index-filter`. Thank you so much for that. It works much better.

Answer (score 1):

After having to do this a few times over the years, I took [torek's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222859/2899559) and wrote my overly verbose bash script as a single `git filter-branch`. I'm posting it here, both for other users and future me.

First, just to clarify how I did the `lfs migrate import` (and I'm sure I took the long route for some of these lines):

```bash
# Make sure we have the up-to-date remote branches
git submodule update --init SubmodulePath/
cd SubmodulePath/
git fetch --all

# Create local branches that mirror the remote ones
git branch -lr | grep -v "origin/HEAD" | sed 's/^.*origin\///' | 
   xargs -I @ git branch @ origin/@ --force

#Find all files that git identifies as binary and create the lfs migrate command, then run it
git log --all --numstat | grep '^-' | cut -f3 | sed 's|^.*/\(.*\)|\1|' | sed 's|^.*\.\([^.]*\)|\1|' |
   sort -u --ignore-case | sed 's|\([^0-9]\)|[\L\1\U\1]|g' | awk '{print}' ORS=',*.' |
   sed 's|^\(.*\),\*\.$|git lfs migrate import --everything --object-map=LFSImport.txt --include="*.\1"|' | . /dev/stdin
```

I then moved LFSImport to a different directory (I also committed it to the submodule repo) and ran the `filter-branch` with `index-filter`:

```bash
git filter-branch -f --index-filter '
   numLines=`git ls-files --stage | grep SubmodulePath | wc -l`
   if [ $numLines = 1 ];
   then
     echo 
     oldHash="$(git rev-parse --quiet --verify :SubmodulePath)"
     echo oldHash: $oldHash
     newHash="$(grep  $oldHash /path/to/LFSImport.txt | cut -d , -f2)"
     echo newHash: $newHash
     git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000 $newHash SubmodulePath
   fi
   ' HEAD
```

I probably should have added a check on `$newHash` to see if it wasn't empty (it was in one commit of mine, but I manually just set it to something else that didn't exist). As torek mentioned, this was cleaner, faster and worked just as well, if not better.